# How do we rotate a figure in 2d in openGL with respect to a point (other than the origin)?

Tags: c++, opengl

Using the `glrotatef()` function rotates the figure by a specified angle with respect to the origin. How do I rotate the same figure with respect to another point without making use of transformation matrices manually? Thanks!

```
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gluOrtho2D(0,499,0,499);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    drawhouse();
    glFlush();
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glTranslatef(0.5 ,0.5,0.5);
    glRotatef(45,1,1,1);
    glTranslatef(-0.5 ,-0.5,-0.5);
    drawhouse();
    glFlush();
}
```

Here's a screenshot for what happens. http://postimage.org/image/q81bhupw/

Comment: With `glRotatef` you are actually using rotation matrices without being aware of that. But I know how you mean it and John's answer would be your method of choice.

Comment: Johns answer has a problem right? I have added a comment to his answer .. I just tried out and it doesn work that way.

Comment: John's answer is correct. He just assumed, you know how to apply these operations correctly! Look at my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically:

If you want to rotate around `P`, translate by `-P` (so that `P` moves to the origin), then perform your rotation, then translate by `P` (so that the origin moves back to `P`).

```
glTranslatef(P.x, P.y, P.z);
glRotatef(angle, A.x, A.y, A.z);
glTranslatef(-P.x, -P.y, -P.z);
```

(Note: This is in "reverse order" because the last transformation added is the first one applied, under OpenGL rules.)

So in your setup code, you need these calls:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, 499, 0, 499);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

And then your `display()` method should look something like this:

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glRotatef(45.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
    glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
    drawhouse();
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: Even if u move P to the origin, doesnt the origin itself get displaced to a new point again and the rotation  happens about the new origin?

Comment: No. The rotation happens around `(0, 0, 0)`. OpenGL doesn't "remember" what the original origin was, it uses what the origin is when the transformation is invoked.

Comment: But I just wrote the code as below and that problem arose:
    drawhouse();    
    glTranslatef(0.5 ,0.5,0.5);
    glRotatef(45,1,1,1);
    glTranslatef(-0.5 ,-0.5,-0.5);
    drawhouse();

Comment: I have added it to the main post John, ur answer makes perfect sense , however it doesn seem to work for whatever reason.

Comment: You're calling `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)` and then never calling `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)` again, so you aren't changing what you think you're changing. Also, you shouldn't draw the scene twice every display call (or even change the projection matrix every display call). I don't think your issues have anything to do with rotation.

Comment: ^^ So how do I fix my problem? I've added a screenshot for the resulting output.

Comment: See my edit or Christian's answer. You can either us `glLoadIdentity() `each frame or use his `glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()` pair, they both work.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has quite a few problems. First, you have to apply the transformation on the moelview matrix and not the projection matrix. Second, you should wrap you transformation into a `glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix`, otherwise, they aren't reversed when rendering the next frame. Third, you should apply `gluOrtho2d` on the projection matrix and not the modelview matrx.

In accordance to John's answer your code should look like:

```
void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,499,0,499);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    drawhouse();
    glFlush();
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0.5 ,0.5,0.5);
        glRotatef(45,1,1,1);
        glTranslatef(-0.5 ,-0.5,-0.5);
        drawhouse();
    glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
}
```

**EDIT:** Even (or because) you are afraid of matrices, I suggest you to read some introductory material on vector and matrix operations and transformations. And you should also read some introductory material on OpenGL, to really understand how it works, especially the state machine principle.